# Where can i find pillow module location?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am doing programming assignment, my program contains images so I used pillow module. In the end, I must send all modules file to my lecturer so that he could run my program without installing anything, but I can't find my pillow module location. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Did you install the module? Are you able to use it from *Python*?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I think that you should prepare a requirements file with all dependencies your program needs. Then your lecturer can simply install them using for example `pip`. For more information aboutn pip and requirements file please check https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html

Comment: @CristiFati Yes by pip

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur WIndow 10

Comment: @BenJong you can use `pip show pillow` to find module path in system files or download it from [source](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow)

Comment: we have `pip` and `venv` to avoid "sending all modules file" via "installing anything"

Comment: Instead of sending all the modules you could try [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). Citing the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.4/operating-mode.html): *You distribute the bundle as a folder or file to other people, and they can execute your program. To your users, the app is self-contained. They do not need to install any particular version of Python or any modules. They do not need to have Python installed at all.* Be careful about different OS versions though.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov i must send him the file else the program wouldn't run

Answer (score 3):

```
pip show pillow
```

should return **Location**

Answer (score 1):

Although *pip* is the right thing to do it, you can use *python* interpreter directly as an alternative (this works for modules that were not installed by *pip*), which would output the module entry-point's location. As a note, the module must be **importable**.

Here's an example for *numpy* (as I don't have *pillow* installed):

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053170620>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import numpy
> >>> numpy
> <module 'numpy' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\VEnvs\\py35x64_test\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>
> ```

Or the one line corespondent:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q053170620>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import numpy; print(numpy)"
> <module 'numpy' from 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\VEnvs\\py35x64_test\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>
> ```